# "And her air of intently, secretly listening, bordered, I felt, upon the uncanny" - how to replace "air" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

Reading an old story, I am trying to figure out the meaning of "air"in the following sentence:

> But ‘mother’ listened the whole time—not to me. Her thoughts were all
> elsewhere. *And her air of intently, secretly listening, bordered, I
> felt, upon the uncanny*.

I read the dictionary entries but still cannot really understand the meaning in this context. What would be the best re-phrasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *air* here means manner. If you remove all the secondary members of the sentence, it will turn from:

```
And her air of listening, bordered upon the uncanny.
```

to:

```
And her manner of listening, bordered upon the uncanny.
```

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/air (noun, 6)

> the peculiar look, appearance, and bearing of a person

Comment: Thank you. One clarification, if you do not mind - what does the "uncanny" relate to? The manner of listening, or listening itself? It does not make much sense in either case :(

Comment: It is related to the manner, like `And her manner, it was so mysterious, almost (bordered upon) uncanny`. @JohnV